# private add-on to a public project using Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I have a small open-source C++ project, hosted on Bitbucket using Mercurial.
Now, I am developing a new feature which adds a couple of new files and new build targets; otherwise it does not change the existing files.

I have opened a new branch, but after I pushed it to the main repo I was told that I cannot make the new feature open .. so I closed the repo and started looking for a solution. I have two questions:

1. What would have been a good approach for this situation? I need something that allows me to synchronize fixes made to the common code between the public and private repo. I do not mind having the private code only locally. I found two things:

   - using private stage for the new branch; but I don't know how to get fixes I make in the secret branch to the common files over to the open repo
   - using subrepos; this would need some code restructuring, but might be cleaner .. it just bothers me that this is marked as "feature of last resort" in the documentation.
2. How do I fix the situation where I have already pushed the closed code the the repo? Would it help to strip the branch and push, or do I need to delete the repo from Bitbucket and create a new one?

Comment: As to synchronization: sounds to me like that's what merges are for... hard to really go into detail without having really any detail :)

As a side note: If it's really an open-source project, you can fork it without questions being asked and no-one has the authority asking you to not do so and sharing your work publicly (if you follow the license; sometimes a name is branded and you might need to rename stuff).

Comment: @planetmaker: I do not need to fork, as I am the sole developer of the project. I keep it open source so other people (mostly students) can use it in their code.

Comment: @planetmaker: As for the merges, I am not sure how to merge commits from the private branch, if they include changes to both the public and private files - wouldn't this copy the private files to the public repo?

Comment: Use two repos: one public one, one private one. Do everything you can do in the public one. Do what you can do in private only in the private one. Do regular merges from the public repo to your private one in order to get the features over from public to private

Answer (score 1):

Since I am happy with having the private branch only locally, I have done the following:

- I stripped the private branch from the bitbucket repo as well as my local copy of that repo.
- In my copy of the private repo, I merged the changes from the public to to private branch and also then copied any common files changed in the private branch into the public one.
- Then I marked the whole private branch as 'secret', to keep it local.

For future work, I plan to using `hg merge` for moving changes from the public to the private branch and `hg graft` for the reverse direction.

As far as I can see, this should work...